# how to map StreamResourceinfo to a absolute URL

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am using the below snipped to save an audio file in the isolated storage. but the exception occurs when streamresourceinfo mapped to a absoluteUri. The uri accepts only the relative uri. Please guide me how to save the audio file using absolute Uri.

```
private void SaveMp3()
    {
        string FileName = "Audios/Deer short.mp3";
        FileName = "http://www.ugunaflutes.co.uk/Deer short.mp3";
        StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(FileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(FileName))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(FileName);
            }

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Audio.png", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    Stream resourceStream = streamResourceInfo.Stream;
                    long length = resourceStream.Length;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                    int readCount = 0;
                    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(streamResourceInfo.Stream))
                    {
                        // read file in chunks in order to reduce memory consumption and increase performance
                        while (readCount < length)
                        {
                            int actual = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            readCount += actual;
                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, actual);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Application.GetResourceStream` to load an external resource, because `URI` must to be relative to the application package http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.95).aspx. 
You need  to use `WebClient.OpenReadAsync` to download your mp3 file and after save it locally to `IsolatedStorage`, peace of example:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                                               {
                                                   if (args.Error != null)
                                                   {
                                                       //save file here
                                                   }
                                               };

            webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://www.ugunaflutes.co.uk/Deer short.mp3"));
```